# Html Agility Pack merged queries

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, html-parsing, html-agility-pack

I have a table kind of:

```
...some td's with not needed links
<td>1010</td>
<td>Building</td>
<td>Adress stree 55</td>
<td>00000 City</td>
<td>
<a href="http://www.adress.xy/file.kml" target="_self">
<img align="top" border="1" src="/custom/img/kml.gif" alt="Details" title="Details" />
</a>
</td>
```

I use this query to get the innertext information:

```
HtmlDocumet doc = new HtmlDocument();
        doc.LoadHtml(html);            
        var node = doc.DocumentNode.Descendants("table")
            .FirstOrDefault(x => x.Attributes["style"].Value == "table-layout:auto")
            .Elements("tr")
            .Select(tr => tr.Elements("td").Select(td => td.InnerText).ToArray)).ToArray();
```

but I would also like to add to the array an url with .kml links.
So the question is: how is it possible to merge querys to get innertext and the kml link?

the result of this query is:

```
string[i][j]
```

where i= number of tr- elements and j - number of td- elements

Example:

```
string[0][0]="1010"
string[0][1]="Building"
```

I would like also to have: `string[i][4] = "http://www.adress.xy/file.kml"`

P.S. [the whole table is here.](http://www.rwth-aachen.de/go/id/yvu/scol/1/sasc/1/pl/313)

Comment: Could you include a more complete example of your table and explain precisely what you are trying to make arrays of?  Give some examples of what data you want and how you want it presented.  It isn't clear to me what you're trying to get since your explanation and code references elements that you do not show in your examples.

Comment: here is the table: http://goo.gl/Mt3Bq
I get a string[][] back. so that string[0][0]="1010", [0][1]="Building"

The first array adress increments with new <tr> and the second one with new <td> element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't worry about getting arrays of arrays, it would be better if you got lists instead.

```
const string url = "http://www.rwth-aachen.de/go/id/yvu/scol/1/sasc/1/pl/313";
const string kml = "http://www.adress.xy/file.kml";
var newKml = new[] { kml };

var web = new HtmlWeb();
var doc = web.Load(url);
var xpath = "//table[@style='table-layout:auto']/tr[td]";
var rows = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes(xpath);
var table = rows
    .Select(row =>
        row.Elements("td")
           .Skip(1)
           .Take(4)
           .Select(col => System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlDecode(col.InnerText))
           .Concat(newKml)
           .ToList()
    ).ToList();
```

I would consider making an anonymous type to represent your rows that way you could give more useful names you your columns.  Perhaps even put the results in a `DataTable` instead.

Just in case you won't be able to use xpath for whatever reason (or you wanted to know the equivalent LINQ queries), you could replace the line that uses the xpath with this:

```
var rows = doc.DocumentNode.Descendants("table")
    .Where(t => t.Attributes["style"].Value == "table-layout:auto")
    .SelectMany(t => t.Elements("tr").Where(tr => tr.Elements("td").Any()));
```

Comment: Windows Phone don't support XPath.

Comment: Wait, this is XPath within HAP not the framework so that shouldn't matter.  But even if it wasn't supported, it could be easily corrected.

Comment: The HAP package for Windows Phone don't have the XPath, as it have a dependency on `System.Xml.Xpath` which isn't available ;-) But yes, it's easy to workaround, just thought I'd mention it.

Comment: A relative new project to emulate XPath support is [described in this blog post](http://socialebola.wordpress.com/2011/07/06/xpath-support-for-the-html-agility-pack-on-windows-phone/)

Comment: Ah, thanks for pointing that out.  I thought all implementations had the same features.

Comment: thank you for your responce. but I have a limited version if HAP, because I am using this dll for Windows Phone 7 project.
so SelectNodes(xpath) is not working. the only thing I can do is: 
var rows = doc.DocumentNode.Descendants(xpath); But it cannot evaluate this expression :(

Comment: @Claus: it is not possible at the time to download the package. I only receive HTTP Error 503, Service Unavailable

Comment: Don't use xPath then. I use HAP in many of my projects, without xPath. Works just fine.

Comment: @Pamp: Use the alternative code on the bottom in place of the XPath code.  That's exactly why I included it.

Comment: @Jeff: thank you for your responce, but with linq querie I get almost the whole html node. I would like to get only the Innertext and the value of <a href  ...
I am a beginner in linq, so any tries from me to create such a query failed. Could you please help me with that?

Comment: @Pamp: There is no innertext in the anchor.  From what you gave of your example, you wanted the contents of the first four columns and replace the fifth with your new kml file.  That's what the above code does.  Is that not what you wanted?